# include content of input in function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to include the content of a text box (to be sent to a function via function call).
currently I have

```
<form name="blah">
<input type="text" name="compdate" id="compdate" readonly onClick="GetDate(this);" />
<input type="button" onClick="ajaxwin.load('ajax', 'apptoshop.php?sid='.$_GET['sid'].'&doc=XXXX', ' '); return false">
</form>
```

I need to include the content of compdate where you see XXXX however I have no idea how to do it. any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to add an ID to the button by any chance? Your code would be much more maintainable with proper unobtrusive JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified code:

```
<form name="blah">
<input type="text" name="compdate" id="compdate" readonly onClick="GetDate(this);" />
<input type="button" onClick="ajaxwin.load('ajax', 'apptoshop.php?sid='.$_GET['sid'].'&doc=document.blah.compdate.value', ' '); return false">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the textbox use simple javascript

```
document.getElementById("compdate").value
```

Or you can use jQuery

```
$('#compdate').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'&doc='+$("#compdate").val()
```

Comment: hey I only added a small amount. OP should extract to function possibly

Comment: Yes I know, sorry directing it mostly at OP. `=]`